# Substring a variable with retaining original variable

Tags: jsp

I have a variable which I am displaying in jsp. If the length of this variable is more than 20 chars it have to display up to 20 chars followed by "..." and when user hovers over variable it will display full value. For this I have to retain full variable as well as sub-stringed one. How can I achieve that?

Comment: The problem is easily understandable and answered. :) So it doesn't lack sufficient information to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it with pure CSS using [`text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) property.

```
.ellipsis {
  width: 10em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.ellipsis:hover {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: normal;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

And use it like that:

```
<div class="ellipsis">your_very_long_string</div>
```